# How to mock import inside a method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

This is a pretty straightforward question. If I have an import inside a method, how can I mock this specific import? For example:

```
def myFunction(self):
    auth_token_path = self.authTokenPath()
    import json

    if os.path.exists(auth_token_path):
      auth_token = json.load(open(auth_token_path, 'r'))
      return auth_token
```

How can I mock this "import json"? Is there any way to patch this? I tried to import inside my test function, but I don't think it is the right way to do it (and it didn't work also).

Comment: What do you mean by "mocking"? Not actually importing? Why not delete or comment the `import` statement?

Comment: Do you want to mock this very line inside `myFunction` so that some other module/object was assigned to `json` variable? Not sure if this possible since `json` variable is available in the local scope of `myFunction`.

Comment: I'm trying to write a test code for this function, so I have to mock external functions calls such as json.load. however, I don't know how to mock specifically this json import and .load

Answer (score 0):

To mock this function

```
def myFunction(self):
auth_token_path = self.authTokenPath()
import json

if os.path.exists(auth_token_path):
  auth_token = json.load(open(auth_token_path, 'r'))
  return auth_token
```

All we need to do is add the decorator PATCH() related to the import's function one needs to mock:

```
@patch('json.load')
def myFunction(self,json):
    auth_token_path = self.authTokenPath()
    import json

    if os.path.exists(auth_token_path):
       auth_token = json.load(open(auth_token_path, 'r'))
    return auth_token
```

Comment: You're not actually mocking the import itself; you're just replacing `json.load` after the import succeeds.